# Suppress warning message Akka.net

Tags: c#, akka.net

I'm a newbie on Akka.NET so excuse me if this question is silly.

I've tried to suppress the following Akka.NET warning

"NewtonSoftJsonSerializer has been detected as a default serializer.
It will be obsoleted in Akka.NET starting from version 1.5 in the favor of Hyperion
for more info visit: http://getakka.net/docs/Serialization#how-to-setup-hyperion-as-default-serializer
If you want to suppress this message set HOCON 'akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning' config flag to on."

But I'm not entirely sure where can I set that flag.

So far I've tried

```
var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(@"
akka {
    actor {
       akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning = true
          }
     }");
TlogSystem = ActorSystem.Create("TlogSystem",config);
```

But it doesn't work, it keep printing the warning. Could someone point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `suppress-json-serializer-warning` outside the `actor` block:

```
akka {
    suppress-json-serializer-warning = on
}
```

Comment: @KevinMiranda, a quick googling of the actual warning message says it should be "on", not "true". I've updated my answer, give it another shot!

Comment: Ignore my last comment, didn't see you writed "suppress-json-serializer-warning = on" instead of "akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning = on", it worked. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: It did worked with "suppress-json-serializer-warning = true" so "on" or "true" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the warning can be switched off in some way, but you could also consider doing what the warning says.. that is.. use Hyperion instead of Json for serializing in Akka. It can be done in the Config as follows:

```
     akka {
                serializers {
                  hyperion = ""Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion""
                }
                serialization-bindings {
                  ""System.Object"" = hyperion
                }
          }
```